# C++ enforcing implementing a pure virtual method from a different inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance, pure-virtual

I have a `Parent` class and two `Child` classes:

```
class Parent
{
};

class Child1: public Parent
{
};

class Child2 : public Parent
{
};
```

I would like a second class hierarchy, with class `Cousin` at the top of the hierarchy and subclasses called `Cousin1`, `Cousin2` etc:

```
class Cousin
{
    virtual void doUsefulWork() = 0;
};

class Cousin1 : public Cousin
{
    virtual void doUsefulWork() override
    {
        // One behaviour
    }
};

class Cousin2 : public Cousin
{
    virtual void doUsefulWork() override
    {
        // A different behaviour
    }
};
```

Each `Child` subclass MUST inherit a `Cousin` subclass, to have an implementation of `doUsefulWork()`:

```
class Child1 : public Parent, Cousin1
{
    // Has implementation of doUsefulWork() from Cousin1
};
```

**How can I guard against the author of a `Child` subclass forgetting to inherit a `Cousin` subclass?** I would like something which generates a compile time error.

Every `Child` subclass must have access to an implementation of `doUsefulWork()`.

I was thinking of making `Cousin` inherit from Parent and defining the pure virtual `doUsefulWork()` in `Parent`, but then I would have complicated multiple inheritance issues in `Child` subclasses?

Comment: I would do it the other way around and inherit `Parent` from `Cousin`. This will at least generate a compile error if an author of a `Child` class forgets to reimplement `doUsefulWork()` or inherit from a class that has an implementation.

Comment: Or vice versa, `class Parent : public Cousin { ...` will do the trick.

Comment: i hope the names are just for the example here. Imho the "child-parent" analogon is one of the worst, as `struct Child : Parent` actually means that every `Child` **is-a** `Parent`, no wonder that it causes confusion when OO is thaught like that

Comment: I'm not sure whether `class Parent: public Cousin {` is such a good idea. Deriving `class Child1: public Parent, Cousin1 {` would have the base class `Cousin` twice (and that smells like the need of virtual inheritance...)

Comment: What I don't understand: `Child1` accessed with a pointer to `Parent` makes the virtual method `doUsefulWork()` invisible. It's a pointer to `Cousin` which is needed. If in turn, `Child3` is accidentally not derived from any `CousinX` with overridden `doUsefulWork()`, assigning it to a pointer to `Cousin` should cause trouble. There is something subtle, I'm not yet aware of.

Comment: Is it necessary that you inherit `Cousin`? An association would be much cleaner anyway. If you have to access protected members of `Cousin` how about making them `friend`s?

Comment: @Scheff  Obviously the child would then inherit only from the Parent directly

Comment: @jlanik I understood it the way, that `Cousin1` should provide an implementation by override. `Cousin` just brings the need for this (by the pure virtual). (as I have understood it)

Comment: @Scheff  I see. Well then children can inherit Cousin1 or Cousin2. It's diamond, but it should be sdafe as long as Cousin contains only pure virtual methods.

Comment: @jlanik Actually, I think there need nothing to be changed. To call the virtual method `doUsefulWork()` the object pointer must be of type `Cousin*` (not `Parent*`). Assigning a pointer to a `ChildX` to `Cousin*` will cause compiler complaints if there is no inheritance from any derived `CousinX`. Actually, I rather see the danger that a `ChildX` is correctly derived from a `CousinX` but not from a `Parent`.

Comment: @Scheff But he does not say anything about whether the Child instances will be accessed through Cousin pointer or reference or some other way. He just says that he wants to make sure that if you make a new class inheriting from Parent, you are required do implement a method `void doUsefulWork()`. Which to me says `Parent: public Cousin`.

Comment: @jlanik I looked into the profile of OP. It seems to me that OP has stronger background in Java where interfaces are more common than multiple inheritance. Regarding this background, OP's question makes sense to me somehow. OP didn't say how she/he actually wants to access `ChildX`. This info would probably be helpful to clarify this.

Comment: @user463035818 Yes I replaced the class names with "basic" ones.

Comment: It isn't clear what your design is in term of relation between classes.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I guard against the author of a Child subclass forgetting to inherit a Cousin subclass? I would like something which generates a compile time error.

The reason you are implementing these interfaces is because there must be functions that consume these interfaces. If an object doesn't implement the interface you get a compiler error when passing the object to that function - that acts as an enforcing check that the object must implement that interface.